# DMARC validation with private domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, dmarc

my understanding is that to get dmarc to authenticate you should have sub domains, and it will fail with private domains on the same SAP.

SAP = example.com
Brand1 = b1.example.com (DMARC PASS)

*if we do this:*
SAP = example.com
Brand1 = brand1.com (DMARC FAIL)

How do we get around this?

There is going to be a case where we will have something like this and need DMARC to pass.

SAP = example.com
Brand1 = brand1.de
Brand2 = brand2.co.nz

In those cases with the different TLD's, we won't be able to use sub domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to ask support to ensure you have multi-bounce domains enabled. Let's assume you are sending from email.example.com today:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Your new private domain populates the from domain: brand2.com
- **DMARC fail** because example.com does not equal brand2.com

What would work:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Private domain populates the from domain: brand2.example.com
- **DMARC pass** because in both cases they use the domain example.com

So in the past this was only safe if all domains involved were part of the same domain name - or if you did not implement DMARC on those domains. There is a new feature called multi-bounce domain. When that is enabled, the system will always change the bounce domain setting to be bounce.[from domain] - like this:

- From domain: brand2.com
- Bounce domain auto-set to: bounce.brand2.com

Hence you can use a PD different from your SAP domain. Multi bounce is enabled upon request, by submitting a support case requesting help setting up multi-bounce domain support for your new private domain.

Here is a good overview of [DMARC in Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/marketing-cloud-dmarc/)

Comment: Thanks Lukas,

Wasn't aware of multi bounce. That would solve the dmarc fail problem with the private domain.